# How to write a generic type that includes all props from one generic type that are not in another?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, higher-order-components

I'm trying to write a generic HOC that takes a component with props TProps and a type TEntry defining an object structure. I want the HOC to return a component which will call a hook to get an object instance of type TEntry from a particular source (in this case a CMS). This resulting component should only require the consumer to provide the props that are not filled in by that CMS data.

I thought that **Exclude<TProps, TEntry>** would work for this, but I'm still ending up with a component that requires all of TProps. Here's what I've tried (this is rather stripped down for simplicity):

```
const withCmsData = <
  TEntry,
  TProps,
>(
  Component: (props: TProps) => (JSX.Element | null),
  fallback: TEntry,
) => {

  return (props: Exclude<TProps, TEntry>) => {
    const { entry } = useCmsEntries<TEntry>({ fallback });
    return <Component {...entry} {...props} />;
  };
};
```

...and here's an example of how you'd use it to create a new component with fewer props:

```
type ArticlePageProps = {
  title: string;
  subTitle: string;
  date: string;
}
const ArticlePage = ({ title, subTitle, date }: ArticlePageProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <div>{subTitle}</div>
      <div>{date}</div>
    </>
  );
}

type ArticleFromCmsProps = {
  title: string;
  subTitle: string;
}
/*
This creates a new component that now only requires a data prop,
which is the one prop from ArticlePageProps that is
not provided by ArticleFromCmsProps:
*/
const fallback: ArticleFromCmsProps = getFallback();
const MyPageWrapper = withCmsData<ArticlePageProps, ArticleFromCmsProps>(ArticlePage, fallback); 

const render = () => {

  const data = new Date();
  <MyPageWrapper date={date} />
}
```

In the above example, I expect to get a component that requires only the date prop, but instead, at design-time in VSCode I'm getting warnings that the component still requires all 3 props from ArticlePageProps -- `<MyPageWrapper date={date} />` is showing up with the error message that is is missing the `title` and `subtitle` properties

Is there a way to get the *generic* HOC I want? One that returns a component only requiring props not specified by the TEntry type parameter?

Comment: A few example calls to `withCmsData` and the expected types would be pretty nice

Comment: @kellys, I've included an example of component creation from the HOC.

Comment: Ok, I think it's just `Omit<ArticlePageProps, keyof ArticleProps>` then, so it would be `Omit<TEntry, keyof TProps>`

Comment: @kellys, that's not quite working. the call to <Compoent {...entry} {...props} /> now isn't satisfied: `Type 'Omit<TProps, keyof TEntry>' is not assignable to type 'TProps'.
    'TProps' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Omit<TProps, keyof TEntry>'.`

Comment: @Faust Your example shows a generic type parameter being used with `useCmsEntries`, but type information can't affect runtime return types, so the generic `TEntry` is either not needed in your HOF, or you should update the example with the real data that represents your issue.

Comment: @jsejcksn, I've added a "fallback" prop to useCmsEntries to bring it closer to my actual code (the full hook is too long and complicated to include here), which may help explain how type inferencing will work without supplying the type parameter explicitly, though I'm leaving in the explicit params in my example code.

Comment: @Faust The actual signature matters a great deal in this scenario when dealing with generic inference, having a strong effect on the answers you might receive. Does the updated information accurately represent the details and constraints of your situation? (There are lots of answers on SO where an answer provides an accurate and complete solution to the details in the question, but then the asker follows up with "well, actually, the real problem is different in regard to this detail...")

Answer (score 1):

I've included some type utilities to reduce repetition, but the core idea is that you accept the fallback object and the component that you desire to render, inferring their types using generics to create the abstracted component signature which uses the utility [`Omit<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to create the props.

> Due to issues in the way TS deals with [function parameter bivariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance), the `Props` type of `FunctionComponent` needs to be fairly permissive in order to avoid needing to overwrite component and prop types using [assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) in the HOF body.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-BCISSZwGVGbHJIICNCQ+rcumsydC1FU4NmOpBDI1a1vWGAyNishtrwMhJelpTsFl+FMXeD4DRgbVSJ1OoHKt8DccwBUKlAOBgGw7jAsOVDvF6ipAdOs63gu0L9OtcxBFtBVsYcTXHad52XRZ3WwryGD8oKRwQDGgNDRgZ0XVdvQStKnGaBshbFp2ZYVsRgC8G4AsjuqIdCEfBZEL9NViCMGT2PsMCNxWAAIqO1PeTAEBhAAyj6PNdpk1PsZ08PZkjIPuAzgIIAzCXglxECzKIKhAA)

```ts
import {
  default as React,
  type ReactElement,
} from 'react';

// You didn't show this type in your question, so I made a best-effort guess:
declare function useCmsEntries <T>(param: { fallback: T; }): { entry: T };

type FunctionComponent<Props extends object = any> = (props: Props) => ReactElement | null;
type ComponentProps<Component extends FunctionComponent> = Parameters<Component>[0];

type ComponentWithExcludedProps<
  Props extends object,
  Component extends FunctionComponent<Props>,
> = FunctionComponent<Omit<ComponentProps<Component>, keyof Props>>;

type ArticlePageProps = {
  date: string;
  subTitle: string;
  title: string;
};

function createComponentWithoutFallbackProps<
  IncludedProps extends object,
  C extends FunctionComponent,
>(
  fallback: IncludedProps,
  Component: C,
): ComponentWithExcludedProps<IncludedProps, C> {
  return (props) => {
    const { entry } = useCmsEntries<IncludedProps>({ fallback });
    // Make sure you spread these in the desired order: props in the latter will overwrite the former
    const all: ComponentProps<C> = {...entry, ...props};
    return <Component {...all} />;
  };
}

declare const ArticlePage: (props: ArticlePageProps) => ReactElement;
type ArticleFromCmsProps = Pick<ArticlePageProps, 'subTitle' | 'title'>;
declare const fallback: ArticleFromCmsProps;

const MyPageWrapper = createComponentWithoutFallbackProps(fallback, ArticlePage);
type MyPageWrapperProps = Parameters<typeof MyPageWrapper>[0]; // { date: string; } 

const render = () => {
  const date = new Date().toISOString();
  <MyPageWrapper date={date} /> // ok
};
```